# Cannot import Cloud function environment variables in javascript (Vue.js) app

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Using the instructions from the [Google Cloud Functions environment variables config instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env) I have created env vars for my development environment using the Firebase CLI:

```
Terminal:
> firebase functions:config:set fbconfig.apikey="[VALUE]" 
fbconfig.projectid="[VALUE]" fbconfig.storagebucket="[VALUE]" 
fbconfig.messageingsenderid="[VALUE]" fbconfig.databaseurl="[VALUE]" 
fbconfig.authdomain="[VALUE]"
```

In my Vue.js app (running Nuxt.js) I have the following in my Firebase init file used when making requests to the project's Firebase Firestore db:

```
// firebaseInit.js
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/functions'
import 'firebase/firestore'
import 'firebase/auth'
import 'firebase/storage'

// const functions = require('firebase/functions');

const config = {
  apiKey: firebase.functions().config().fbconfig.apikey,
  authDomain: firebase.functions().config().fbconfig.authdomain,
  databaseURL: firebase.functions().config().fbconfig.databaseurl,
  projectId: firebase.functions().config().fbconfig.projectid,
  storageBucket: firebase.functions().config().fbconfig.storagebucket,
  messagingSenderId: firebase.functions().config().fbconfig.messagesenderid
}

firebase.initializeApp(config)
```

When I hardcode the config values everything works, however when I try to reference the env variable through Firebase functions (e.g., using `firebase.functions().config().fbconfig.apikey) they cannot be found and I receive the error:

```
Browser Console:
Uncaught FirebaseError {code: "app/no-app", message: "Firebase: No Firebase 
App '[DEFAULT]' has been cre…- call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-
app).", name: "[DEFAULT]", stack: "[DEFAULT]: Firebase: No Firebase App 
'[DEFAULT]' h…ntext (http://localhost:3000/_nuxt/app.js:4459:9)"}
```

I've spent way too much running through the Firebase docs and believe I'm following them correctly but can't seem to figure out why I cannot access the vars through the app.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: It looks like the code in your `firebaseInit.js` runs client-side in the browser, where `firebase.functions` is not available.

Comment: Thanks much for the reply, @FrankvanPuffelen Maybe I'm not understanding, but I thought the purpose of using the firebase/functions import was to make available access to the firebase functions so I can pull in remote values. When I run `firebase functions:config:get` from the command line I'm able to recall the variables I set but I cannot get the values from inside my app. I thought that was the use case as described in the firebase documentation I linked to.

Comment: Cloud Functions run server-side, and indeed have access to the environment variables. But from what I can see, the code in your `firebaseInit.js` runs client-side, where the environment variables are not available.

Comment: So if I successfully set the variables on the server, do you know how to retrieve them from the server? The docs are telling to use the firebase/functions API to retrieve them.

Comment: Cloud Functions run on a server, so can access the environment variables. And you can indeed write a Cloud Function that you then call from your web app. But the configuration variables are not automatically accessible from the web app. That would sort-of defeat their purpose, since these environment variables are often used to store secret keys/values.

Comment: Thanks for the help (and patience). Is there a sample or doc somewhere you can point me to?